# Serving static content with nginx alias, what is the difference between /dir and /dir/?

Tags: nginx, server

I'm setting up an nginx server to serve an `index.html` page that I have stored in `/data/www/test/`.

Here is my config file (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /test/ {
        alias /data/www/test/;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

I can `curl 0:80` and see the contents of `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`.

I can `curl 0:80/test/` and see the contents of `/data/www/test/index.html`.

But when I `curl 0:80/test` I get a 404.

I want to be able to see that html whether I type `/test` or `/test/`.

Can someone please explain what is happening here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just like the format, request for `/test` return test file, the config will match `location /` and find test file in `root` path. **you can try doing `touch /usr/share/nginx/html/test` and access `/test` again**

Request for `/test/` will match `location /test/`, at the content phase, it look the index file in the `root/alias` specified location.